# Not Able to Select multiple CheckBoxs in Telerik Grid using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am using Telerik grid in my application. I inserted a GridViewCheckBoxColumn at first column of the grid. The check boxes created successfully but i am not able to check multiple check boxes. I am able to check single checkbox only.

How can i check multiple checkboxes?

```
 And also i want to know that checked row counts in the telerik gridview because i am using collection to bind the data in the GridView. In that collection How shall i get the selected rows?
```

Please tell me some suggestion to solve these problems

Here is my code

// AvailablePacks is getting all the rows in the grid view

```
 foreach (var pack in AvailablePacks)    
 {
       if (SelectedPack != null)
       {
            var cachedPack = AvailablePacks.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Casepack.CasePackId == pack.Casepack.CasePackId);    
            ((IList<CasePackPivotRow>)AvailablePacks).Add(SelectedPack );    
            this.SelectedPacks.Remove(SelectedPack );
       }
 }
```

And here is my XAML code for creating check box in gridview:

```
<telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn Header="" 
    Width="15" 
    EditTriggers="CellClick" 
    AutoSelectOnEdit="True" 
    DataMemberBinding="{Binding Selection, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

What i have to select multiple checkboxes in the grid?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: GridViewCheckBoxColumn binds to item property so its impossible that you can't check more than one unless you're changing other properties when one is checked. Btw for me it looks like you're using GridViewSelectColumn or trying to use.

Comment: Hi this is my XAML file to create checkbox in gridview <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn Header="" Width="15" EditTriggers="CellClick" AutoSelectOnEdit="True" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Selection, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

Comment: What are you saying , I cant get you...Please Can you explain about it a little more ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

telerik said : 
SOLUTION

In order to implement the desired requirement, first subscribe to the ValueChanged event and then execute the following code snippet in the ValueChanged event handler:

```
 void radGridView1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { 

  RadCheckBoxEditor editor = sender as RadCheckBoxEditor; 

  if (editor != null && (bool)editor.Value == true) 

   { 

    this.radGridView1.GridElement.BeginUpdate(); 

    foreach (GridViewDataRowInfo row in this.radGridView1.Rows) 

    { 

        if (row != this.radGridView1.CurrentRow) 

        { 

            row.Cells["Bool"].Value = false; 

        } 

    } 

    this.radGridView1.GridElement.EndUpdate(); 

}
```

}